# Restricting zoom direction of an interactive D3 map projection

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

A bit of forewarning: I am very new to Javascript, D3, and code in general. The code that enables the zoom functionality that I'm asking for help with is still quite confusing to me. So, sorry in advance if this is a stupid question!

First off, [here is the map that I have so far](http://josh.apos.tl/d3).

Right now, when an electorate is clicked, it is centred and zoomed in upon. I lifted this functionality with some slight alteration from [this bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675).

The issue I'm having is that when the electorate called 'West Coast-Tasman' is clicked, the current function that calculates the map's zoom level causes the map to zoom out. How could I restrict the zoom functionality from zooming out when an electorate is clicked (without restricting it from zooming out when the map is reset)?

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't add more than 2 links to my question, so [here's a link](http://imgur.com/lqxYFBv) to an image that points out the 'West Coast-Tasman' electorate.

Comment: You can restrict the zoom level by setting the `.scaleExtent()` of the zoom behaviour appropriately.

Comment: Ah, that's what I had assumed. I've played around with it a fair bit, but I've had no luck understanding how to alter it properly for my purposes (no matter what min/max values I give it, I'm not able to discern a difference in the map's zoom behaviour). I've looked in the d3 wiki, but am still confused. Do you know of any resources that either explain how it works more in depth, or that might address using it for this purpose?

Comment: Hmm, well it looks like something's going wrong with the calculation of the extent of that electorate. Maybe there's a bug in the geodata?

Comment: Could be, there's an issue with another electorate, [Rongotai](http://imgur.com/ME7gMbJ), that's causing the map to zoom out a huge distance. I'll see if replacing the GeoJSON clears it up. Thanks!!